# Github Python API accessing file content after get_files()

Tags: github-api, pygithub

I'm looking to access the content files that were changed in a github pull request using pygithub. I've managed to get  a list of the files using

```
repo = gh.get_repo(repo_url)
pr = repo.get_pull(30)

for file in pr.get_files():
    print(file)
```

But I don't know how to access the contents of the file. I see it has a filename and sha.

Answer (score 0):

The `filename` method will return the name of each file. You can then use the `get_contents` method to get each file's content.

```
from github import Github

github = Github('user', 'token')
user = github.get_user()
repository = user.get_repo('YourRepository')

pr = repository.get_pull(30)
filelist = []

for file in pr.get_files():
    filelist.append(file.filename)

for each_file in filelist:
    print(repository.get_contents(each_file))
```